# Failing at downloading GWT plugin for eclipse 4.3

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins, timeout

I cannot seem to get anything but a 404 in the browser or a timeout message in eclipse when trying to access this file

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/core/4.3/zips/gpe-e43-latest-updatesite.zip

Can anyone else reach it, maybe I'm just blocked for some reason now at work? I was able to download the plugin once, during my first week.  Now I cannot check for updates or anything.

I followed a few other posts about the subject and have come up with nothing.

Comment: URL you've posted is working for me. Just check it again.

Comment: I must be blocked at work, thank you for checking!